# Python in AWS Lambda giving indent error on line that doesn't even exist

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to setup a simple aws lambda function and no matter what python I put in the function it's returning an error on a line that's not even in the function.

What I started with:

```
def hello(event, context):
    print("hi i")
    return "hello-world"
```

What I"m at now:

```
def hello(event, context):
    pass
```

No matter what the body of the function is, when I test it I get this error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'handler'"
}

Request ID:
"6071965c-b7ad-4a9f-aa10-7a81980388f0"

Function logs:
START RequestId: 6071965c-b7ad-4a9f-aa10-7a81980388f0 Version: $LATEST
Syntax error in module 'handler': unindent does not match any outer indentation level (handler.py, line 4)

END RequestId: 6071965c-b7ad-4a9f-aa10-7a81980388f0
REPORT RequestId: 6071965c-b7ad-4a9f-aa10-7a81980388f0  Duration: 0.36 ms   Billed Duration: 1 ms   Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 36 MB
```

The function I have now, just "pass" doesn't even have 4 lines, how could it be throwing this error? I'm using Python 2.7 Runtime.

[image: screenshot of my function structure on lambda console]

Thank you!

Comment: Did you press "Deploy" in the AWS console before invoking the lambda. Sounds like it is simply running an old deployment / old code of the lambda.

Comment: This was it, no idea I had to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing
`def hello(event, context):`

to
`def lambda_handler(event, context):`

and rename your file from handler.py to lambda_function.py